# "No impact" stacktrace across all threads of a running process?

Tags: linux, performance, debugging, stack-trace

How can I get stacktraces **across all threads** of an already running process, on Linux x64, in a way that is the least invasive and impacting as possible?

Things I've thought of till now:

- *gdb* - I'm afraid it would slow the process too much, and for too long;
- *[strace+](http://code.google.com/p/strace-plus/)* - no idea what performance it has, any experience anybody? still, IIUC, it traces only syscalls, and I can't even expect each thread enters a syscall, specifically some threads may be already hanging;
- *force crash & get a coredump* - yeah... if I could do that easily, I would probably already be busy debugging... please, let's assume there's no elephant in the room, for the purpose of this question, ok?... pretty please...

Answer (score 1):

There's a `gcore` utility that comes with `gdb`.  You don't need to force a crash to get a core dump.

Comment: Thanks, found this too in the meantime, sounds better than crashing; still, IIUC, this seems to be just a thin wrapper script over gdb? So my arguments against gdb would still apply?

Comment: @akavel: Your arguments against `gdb` only really apply to the case where you're using `gdb` interactively.  `gcore` only really takes as long as it needs to take to attach, get a core and detach from the process.  Delays in the running process can be imperceptible to a human if little enough memory is in use.

Comment: That's awesome, but I'm still not sure I can be safe, I'd be grateful for more details: especially, _"if little enough memory is in use"_ - the `core` file can take a few GB, so that probably wouldn't work as "little enough"? :) And, secondly, I'm not exactly talking about perception by human, response times are tracked, and milliseconds kinda matter... there are reasons why the app's written in C++... Also, does `gdb` pause the app while getting core or stacktraces?

Comment: @akavel: Yes, gdb pauses the app while doing anything.  It has to; you can't have the stack getting mashed when you're trying to get a stacktrace.  "A few GB" aren't going to get dumped in milliseconds, so you might be SOL there.  You might try writing a `gdb` script of your own that allocates a buffer, calls `backtrace()` or something, and dumps the result.  You can use `addr2line` to clean it up.  I'm not aware of any existing utility that does this.  (Also note that you'll need to do this for each thread, and it's going to be icky.)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what pstack does. See http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pstack1.html